# Getting text input from wear os keyboard

Tags: java, input, wear-os

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new BaseInputConnection(this, true) {
        @Override
        public boolean finishComposingText() {
            super.finishComposingText();
            sendText(getEditable());
            getEditable().clear();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
            super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
            Editable content = getEditable();
            sendText(content);
            content.clear();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int leftLength, int rightLength) {
            super.deleteSurroundingText(leftLength, rightLength);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code in my custom view. It works on Android but not on wear os. Typing on keyboard does nothing. None of the Base input connection methods get called.

I want to get input like normal keyboard would behave and I don't want to use remote input.

PS: I am using galaxy watch 4 (wear os 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
```

setting this solved the issue